# Extrair conteúdo Array para variáveis PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Tenho uma instrução em cURL que invoca um WS. A resposta deste WS é guardada através de:

```
$reference = var_dump(json_decode($exec, true));

return $reference;
```

Atendendo que tenho isto numa função, no outro ficheiro faço a leitura da seguinte forma:

```
$var = ob_get_clean();
```

É então aqui que faço um echo e dá o resultado em baixo:

```php
array(4) {
  ["InvoiceIdOut"]=>
  int(945)
  ["FiscalDocumentNumber"]=>
  string(7) "AAAA945"
  ["InvoiceURL"]=>
  string(34) "http://teste.pt/maistestes/AAAA945"
  ["ErrorMessage"]=>
  NULL
}
```

No entanto, não estou a perceber como consigo retirar os dados e guardar em variáveis.

Comment: Se é esse o array resultante da conversão do JSON, a solução é um simples acesso à variável que guarda este array.
`$resultado['InvoiceIdOut']`.
Se as respostas abaixo não estão funcionando é provável que tu não guardou o resultado do `json_encode()`

Comment: Me parece que o erro está no "var_dump" pq ele não retona nada, é um "void". Associe a variável direto ao json_decode.

Answer (score 2):

## Comando `list` ou `extract`

O PHP possuí um comando chamado [list](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.list.php) que faz a associação de uma tupla de variáveis para os valores de um array. Se o array, como no seu exemplo é associativo (chave-valor), você pode utilizar o comando [extract](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php).

Usando o seu array de exemplo, se você utilizar o `extract`:

```
extract($seu_array);
```

Ele vai criar automaticamente as variáveis com os nomes das chaves:

```
$InvoiceIdOut = 879
$FiscalDocumentNumber = "AAAA879"
$InvoiceURL = "http://teste.pt/maistestes/AAAA879"
$ErrorMessage = null
```

Comment: Não me devolve nada :\

Comment: Complemente sua pergunta com o código que você escreveu.

Comment: não aconselharia a usar `extract()` pois polui todo o escopo da função, sem contar que pode dar conflitos por serem dados de uma fonte externa.

Comment: Tanta resposta nem vi a sua +1

Comment: @Pagotti, pergunta atualizada

Answer (score 2):

O erro está onde tu usa o `var_dump()`.

Olhe a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) do `var_dump()` e verá que esta função não retorna nenhum valor.

O correto seria:

```php
$reference = json_decode($exec, true);
var_dump($reference);
return $reference;
```

Assim o retorno de `json_decode` será armazenado na variável `$reference` ao invés de ser passado para `var_dump` e ser descartado.

Comment: Fiz como mencionou e o resultado é o mesmo que está referido na pergunta.

Comment: Luís, para facilitar o pessoal que está tentando te ajudar faz o seguinte.
1. Nos mostre o que tu recebe do WS
2. O código onde recebe essa string e como faz o parsing dela
3. Mostre mais do seu código, tá difícil descobrir o que tu tem na variável `$exec`, se tem algum erro antes disso que não estamos vendo.

Pois pelo que perguntou, não tem nada errado. É só acessar a informação no array.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como é o nome do seu array mas simulando que ele seja dessa forma:

```
    $array= array(
  "InvoiceIdOut"=>879,
  "FiscalDocumentNumber"=>"AAAA879",
  "InvoiceURL"=>"http://teste.pt/maistestes/AAAA879",
  "ErrorMessage"=> NULL
);
```

Uma forma de acessar o conteudo, seria informando o nome do array,e o seu indice, dessa forma:

```
echo $array['InvoiceIdOut'];
```

Outra forma tambem seria usando o [extract](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php) , que realiza a função que voce quer, de extrair o conteúdo e transforma em variáveis, dessa forma:

```
 extract($array);
 echo $InvoiceIdOut;
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Devolve apenas um  <

Comment: @LuisAssunção faça dessa forma `$array= json_decode($exec, true);` e ai utilize o exemplo da minha resposta

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a função [extract()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php):

Tipo assim:

```
<?php
$foo = array(
    "InvoiceIdOut" => 879,
    "FiscalDocumentNumber" => "AAAA879",
    "InvoiceURL" => "http://teste.pt/maistestes/AAAA879",
    "ErrorMessage" => null,
    );
extract($foo);
echo "\$InvoiceIdOut = $InvoiceIdOut</br>\$FiscalDocumentNumber = $FiscalDocumentNumber</br>\$InvoiceURL = $InvoiceURL</br>\$ErrorMessage = $ErrorMessage</br>";
?>
//saida
$InvoiceIdOut= 879 
$FiscalDocumentNumber = AAAA879
$InvoiceURL = http://teste.pt/maistestes/AAAA879
$ErrorMessage =
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou assim?

```
$array = ["InvoiceIdOut" => 879, "FiscalDocumentNumber"=>"AAAA879","InvoiceURL"=>"http://teste.pt/maistestes/AAAA879", "ErrorMessage"=>NULL]

$invoiceIdOut = $array[0];
$fiscalDocumentNumber = $array[1];
$invoiceURL = $array[2];
$errorMessage = $array[3];
```

Comment: É devolvido o mesmo resultado que no código do @hard.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma simples é fazendo: `$var = $array["valor da chave"]`.

Um exemplo, onde `$array` seria o nome do `array` no seu código.

Código:

```
<?php

$array = array (
  "InvoiceIdOut" => 879,
  "FiscalDocumentNumber" => "AAAA879",
  "InvoiceURL" => "http://teste.pt/maistestes/AAAA879",
  "ErrorMessage" => NULL
);

$InvoiceIdOut = $array["InvoiceIdOut"];
$FiscalDocumentNumber = $array["FiscalDocumentNumber"];
$InvoiceURL = $array["InvoiceURL"];
$ErrorMessage = $array["ErrorMessage"];

echo '<p> InvoiceIdOut: ' . $InvoiceIdOut . '</p>';
echo '<p> FiscalDocumentNumber: ' . $FiscalDocumentNumber . '</p>';
echo '<p> InvoiceURL: ' . $InvoiceURL . '</p>';
echo '<p> ErrorMessage: ' . $ErrorMessage . '</p>';

?>
```

Saída:

```
InvoiceIdOut: 879

FiscalDocumentNumber: AAAA879

InvoiceURL: http://teste.pt/maistestes/AAAA879

ErrorMessage:
```

Comment: É-me devolvido este resultado:  InvoiceIdOut: <

 FiscalDocumentNumber: <

 InvoiceURL: <

 ErrorMessage:

Comment: @LuísAssunção você mudou a variável `$array` de acordo com a do seu código?

Comment: Sim, atualizei entretanto a pergunta.

Comment: @LuísAssunção veja se funciona alterando essa linha: `$reference = var_dump(json_decode($exec, true));`  para esta: `$reference = json_decode($exec, true);`

Comment: Se não usar var_dump não me cria o array.

Comment: @LuísAssunção o problema provavelmente está no modo com que você está retornando os dados do WS. Edite sua pergunta e coloque mais informações do seu código para podermos te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Agradeço a ajuda por todos prestada. Não estava realmente a fazer echo fora da função mas sim o var_dump dentro da função.

Assim, partilho aqui a forma correta:

Função que recebe a resposta do WS:

```
$reference = json_decode($exec, true);
return $reference;
```

Fora da função:

```
$reference = Business::check(...Variáveis...)

echo $reference['InvoiceIdOut'];
echo $reference['FiscalDocumentNumber'];
echo $reference['InvoiceURL'];
```

Obrigado uma vez mais pela ajuda.